# can't get nodejs async loop to print results only once querying firestore

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am having difficulty getting my `Promises.all` to only trigger once. Can you please help me debug this code so that this only prints once.

The Firestore schema is:

```
/As/${ADoc}/Bs/${BDoc}/Cs/${CDoc}/Ds/${DsDocs}
```

I need to get the number of times that `${DsDocs.id}` shows up.

Thanks for you help.

```
var DsCount = []
var allPromises = []

const APromise = db.collection("As").get().then((ADocs) => {
  allPromises.push(APromise)    
  ADocs.forEach((ADoc) => {        
    const BPromise = db.collection(`As/${ADoc.id}/Bs`).get().then((BDocs) => {
      allPromises.push(BPromise)
      BDocs.forEach((BDoc) => {             
        CPromise = db.collection(`As/${ADoc.id}/Bs/${BDoc.id}/Cs`).get().then((CDocs) => {
          allPromises.push(CPromise)
          CDocs.forEach((CDoc) => {
            const CVBPromise = db.collection(`As/${ADoc.id}/Bs/${BDoc.id}/Cs/${CDoc.id}/Ds`).get().then((DsDocs) => { 
              allPromises.push(CVBPromise)
              DsDocs.forEach((DsDoc) => {
                if(DsCount[DsDoc.id] == undefined){
                  DsCount[DsDoc.id] = 1
                }else{
                  DsCount[DsDoc.id] = DsCount[DsDoc.id] + 1                      
                }
                Promise.all(allPromises).then(results => {
                  console.log(DsCount)
                })
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```